# Multiple Zip File downloading using node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io, node-modules

I have node js application where i want to download muliple zip files . There is list off files when user click on download icon downloading should start with downloading size and when user clicked on pause icon it should pause and it should show play option same with stop .

Answer (score 1):

You need to show your work to ask any questions here. Nobody can help with this type of question.
And you should search node package manager directory to find suitable package for your project.
This npm lets you download data from multiple URLs :

[NPM directory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multi-download)